# Comparing multiple values using If , Else if

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm a little bit confused on using If , Else if on my current project...I need to compare 6 values, the smallest one should be prompted by a message box..here's my code

```
if ((sort1 > sort2) || (sort1 > sort3) || (sort1 > sort4) || (sort1 > sort5))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Insertion Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs1 + " ms");
}
else if ((sort2 > sort1) || (sort2 > sort3) || (sort2 > sort4) || (sort2 > sort5))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Selection Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs2 + " ms");
}
else if ((sort3 > sort1) || (sort3 > sort2) || (sort3 > sort4) || (sort3 > sort5))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Bubble Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs3 + " ms");
}
else if ((sort4 > sort1) || (sort4 > sort2) || (sort4 > sort3) || (sort4 > sort5))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Merge Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs4 + " ms");
}
else if ((sort5 > sort1) || (sort5 > sort2) || (sort5 > sort3) || (sort5 > sort1))
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Quick Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs5 + " ms");
}
```

But it will not prompt the smallest number on the messagebox. Do this have a much proper coding rather than using if, else if?
I've also tried using AND but it doesn't work too..

Comment: You can sort the results...

Comment: That's not C. C# perhaps? And what if none of the conditions are true, have you tried adding a single `else` at the end of the chain to see?

Comment: Off the cuff, I'd say replace your ||'s with &&'s...

Comment: what is sortX ? an int?

Comment: Better you use 'switch' statement to avoid confusion, if you want I can show you. First let me know what exactly you want.

Comment: I've tried using && but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure you can use a switch here @JafferWilson

Comment: For example I will input 6 random numbers, and click ok, the smallest one of them should be prompted by a mssgbox saying " the smallest is *number*. @JafferWilson

Comment: @bunniechan29 instead of using so many if and elseif statement, simply use if statement. It will help to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Throw away this code and use a loop instead.

- Put the results in an array.
- Use a variable `int largest_value = 0`.
- Use a variable `int largest_index = -1`.
- Iterate through the array and for each result, check if it is larger than "largest_value".
- If the value was larger, set `largest_value =` the value, and set `largest_index = i;`, where `i` is the loop iterator.

After the loop, `largest_value` will contain the largest value and `largest_index` will point out where in the array this value is found.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Dictionary* and *Linq*:

```
var algorithms = new Dictionary<String, Double>() { // or Dictionary<String, int>
  {"Insertion Sort", sort1},
  {"Selection Sort", sort2},
  ...
};

var best = algorithms
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value)
  .First();

MessageBox.Show(String.Format("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is {0} with the time of {1} ms", best.Key, best.Value));
```

The advantage of using *Linq* is that you can easily create a report you like, for instance let's print out algorothms from fastest to slowest:

```
var data = algorithms
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.Value)
  .Select(pair => String.Format("{0} took {1} ms", pair.Key, pair.Value));

MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would store all the results in a dictionary like so (numbers are made up):

```
Dictionary<string, int>  myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>()
{
    {"Insertion Sort", 12},
    {"Selection Sort ", 35},
    {"Bubble Sort", 42},
    {"Merge Sort", 52},
    {"Quick Sort ", 32}
};

var min = myDictionary.First(kv => kv.Value == myDictionary.Values.Min());
Console.Out.WriteLine("The fastest is " + min.Key + " with a time of " + min.Value + "ms");
```

Which will allow you to test as many algorithm without changing your if/else structure (since you don't use it).

The output is:

> The fastest is Insertion Sort with a time of 12ms

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter with `else if`, but more with the operators you're using - a sorting algorithm is the fastest if it's faster than ALL others, not just one.

So, change the conditions to use the `&&` operators instead of `||`.

Please note, that this is not the best solution (see others' comments for that), it merely is a fox to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change every || to && you want all of them to be true.

Change every > to <, because you want the smallest, not the greatest.

You also have a typo in your last if: you have sort5 > sort1 twice and you don't have sort5>sort4

Comment: I just noticed you had > instead of <

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the following:)

```
if ( !( sort1 < sort2 ) && !( sort1 < sort3 ) && !( sort1 < sort4 ) && !( sort1 < sort5 ) )
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Insertion Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs1 + " ms");
}
else if ( !( sort2 < sort3 ) && !( sort2 < sort4 ) && !( sort2 < sort5 ) )
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Selection Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs2 + " ms");
}
else if ( !( sort3 < sort4 ) && !( sort3 < sort5 ) )
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Bubble Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs3 + " ms");
}
else if ( !( sort4 < sort5 ) )
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Merge Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs4 + " ms");
}
else 
{
    MessageBox.Show("The Best Sorting Technique Algorithm is Quick Sort with the time of " + elapsedMs5 + " ms");
}
```

I suppose that values of sort1, sort2 and etc can be equal each other. In this case the value with the lowest variable name is selected.:)

Comment: How to make an overcomplicated piece of code even less readable :)